# Unknown IP address is kept loggin into my email account

Tags: ipv6

My Google account showed me that this IP address (`2601:2:1080:6bf:596c:862:733b:9ccb`) has logged into my email account multiple times. Is there anyway to track this IP address?

This is not what a common IPv4 address looks like, so I don't know how to track it. I really need to find out where this IP address is located because this person is black mailing me.

Comment: This is an IPv6 address, FYI. Have you changed your password and removed all API access from your email account?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "track" the IP Address? Changing your password should solve the problem.

Comment: You can report it to your ISP... But just guessing; Looks like possibly ComCast IPv6 in Arkansas... Little Rock area.

Comment: Wait. You think that "that's not what a common IP address looks like". So maybe it's your own ip6 number. Have you checked if you are ipv6 capable? You can check that [here](http://test-ipv6.com/).

Comment: @Rik whether he is or not, his ISP could be and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to do a online tracert for ipv6. This is a ipv6 address and it is common for a ipv6, just not your typical ipv4 (which is probably what your used to.) I'm not really sure why you want to know exactly where they live, however you could give this info to google and maybe they could investigate.

You should first change your password and passwords for any other account that share this password. Athomsfere is correct, it appears top be in little rock. Here is the traceroute info:

```
traceroute to 2601:2:1080:6bf:596c:862:733b:9ccb (2601:2:1080:6bf:596c:862:733b:9ccb), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets

 1  2a02:348:82::1 (2a02:348:82::1)  7.583 ms  7.520 ms  7.451 ms
 2  rt-eu02-v2.xl-is.net (2a02:348:2::4)  0.655 ms  0.603 ms  0.604 ms
 3  xe-8-2-1.edge6.Amsterdam1.Level3.net (2001:1900:5:2:2::2775)  1.194 ms  1.121 ms  1.101 ms
 4  vl-51.edge4.Amsterdam1.Level3.net (2001:1900:102:1::9)  1.104 ms vl-52.edge4.Amsterdam1.Level3.net (2001:1900:102:2::9)  1.308 ms  1.132 ms
 5  vl-4060.edge4.London1.Level3.net (2001:1900:5:1::205)  8.681 ms  8.622 ms  8.688 ms
 6  vl-4081.edge3.London1.Level3.net (2001:1900:5:1::105)  8.732 ms vl-4080.edge3.London1.Level3.net (2001:1900:5:1::101)  8.636 ms vl-4081.edge3.London1.Level3.net (2001:1900:5:1::105)  8.658 ms
 7  vl-4086.edge1.NewYork1.Level3.net (2001:1900:6:1::12)  77.318 ms  77.236 ms  77.141 ms
 8  vl-4041.car1.NewYork2.Level3.net (2001:1900:4:1::102)  218.118 ms  218.347 ms  217.964 ms
 9  vl-51.edge1.NewYork2.Level3.net (2001:1900:38:1::5)  77.880 ms  77.915 ms  77.742 ms
10  comcast-level3.NewYork2.level3.net (2001:1900:4:3::272)  81.121 ms  80.985 ms  81.046 ms
11  he-4-3-0-0-cr01.ashburn.va.ibone.comcast.net (2001:558:0:f5ed::1)  85.678 ms  85.560 ms  85.505 ms
12  he-4-10-0-0-cr01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (2001:558:0:f66c::2)  100.898 ms  100.785 ms  100.731 ms
13  te-7-3-ar01.littlerock.ar.lrock.comcast.net (2001:558:0:f6ef::2)  111.407 ms  111.339 ms  111.252 ms
14  te-8-3-ur01.lookoutrd.ar.lrock.comcast.net (2001:558:60:2::2)  109.795 ms  109.792 ms  109.819 ms
15  te-9-2-ur01.nlittlerock.ar.lrock.comcast.net (2001:558:60:3::1)  115.071 ms  114.483 ms  115.321 ms
16  2001:558:62:28::2 (2001:558:62:28::2)  114.275 ms  114.124 ms  114.310 ms
17  * 2001:558:4002:1:21d:ceff:fe7b:7a1f (2001:558:4002:1:21d:ceff:fe7b:7a1f)  135.239 ms *


 ---- Finished ------
```